# Access 2007 - 'rotating' data without using a crosstab query

Tags: ms-access, dynamic, join, crosstab

I have a query that returns data like this:

```
Store    Product    CasesPerStore
Bob's    Original       2
Bob's    Super          1
Tom's    Original       5
Pete's   Original       9
Pete's   Super          2
```

And I want to join it to another query by Store, to end up with this:

```
Other query headings....       Store    Original CasesPerStore    Super CasesPerStore
Other query data........       Bob's             2                        1
Other query data........       Tom's             5
Other query data........       Pete's            9                        2
```

I can do this to the original data using a crosstab query, but I then can't reference the new crosstab headings (e.g. [Original CasesPerStore] and [Super CasesPerStore]) in a join, probably because they are dynamic i.e. the headings could change depending on what products are in the data at that point.

So how can I join to this 'rotated' data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance how many products there are, *and they are permanently fixed*, then this simplistic solution may be enough. By using `Iif` statements you can get around the pivoting of data but it's hard-coded SQL.

```
SELECT tbl.Store,
   SUM(Iif([Product] = "Original", [CasesPerStore], 0)) AS [Original CasesPerStore],
   SUM(Iif([Product] = "Original", 0, [CasesPerStore])) AS [Super CasesperStore]
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY tbl.Store
```

Comment: Yup that works, thanks very much - I was thinking of a similar solution last night but I've never used Iif so wouldn't have got to this stage without the help. :)